# Looping through multi-checkbox selections in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Aiming to display multiple icons a user checks off when creating a new post in the view.

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= check_box_tag 'post[tech_icon][]', 'fa-diamond', checked('fa-diamond'), id: "message_area" %>
<%= check_box_tag 'post[tech_icon][]', 'fa-html5', checked('fa-html5'), id: "message_area" %>
<%= check_box_tag 'post[tech_icon][]', 'fa-css3', checked('fa-css3'), id: "message_area" %>
```

**show.html.view**

```
<% current_user.posts.each do |post| %>
  * bellow only renders one checked selections (the last one checked)
  <span><i class="fa <%= post.tech_icon %>"></i></span>

  * bellow just renders the selected option text on the screen
  <%= post.tech_icon %> 
<% end %>
```

*** If you have a better title I can throw up there please let me know.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: you mean all checkboxes result are not saving in DB ?

Comment: They are saving to DB - I'm looking to display the selected options in the view. Currently <%= post.tech_icon %> renders all selected options text - however the multiple option selected that i want to display are font-awesome icons not text - above I've showed how my code is.

Comment: what is the output of this  <%= post.tech_icon %>  in above case, I mean if you select more than one choice?

Comment: @Thorin I've updated post with an image: Depending on which one you select: fa-diamond, fa-html5 or fa-css3. if you select all of them it will show all 3 in text. Passing it into the class <i class="fa <%= post.tech_icon %>"> displays one of the icons.

Comment: I have added my answer I hope that will help

Comment: tech_icon is a field in posts table ?

Comment: @Thorin Post(id: integer, title: string, content: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, user_id: integer, slug: string, tech_icon: string)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this:

```
  <span><i class="fa <%= post.tech_icon %>"></i></span>
```

with

```
<% post.tech_icon.split(",").each do |icon| %>
    <span><i class="fa <%= icon %>"></i></span>
 <% end unless post.tech_icon.blank? %>
```

Comment: Error an undefined method `split'.

Comment: I am not able to see any image attached with this question

Comment: if your text(post.tech_icon) like this: fa-diamond fa-html5 fa-css3 then split will work

Comment: can you just add output <%= post.tech_icon %> here when you select all choices?

Comment: Yes all show when I select all options added image. Added image above under error picture

Comment: It seems to me post.tech_icon not a string, can you provide me output of this line post.tech_icon.class  ?

Comment: When I added the migration to posts i added tech_icon:string => Post(id: integer, title: string, content: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, user_id: integer, tech_icon: string) - image above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112916/discussion-between-thorin-and-manuel-quintanilla).